# Contraction mapping in $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-operators

> Suppose $T$ is an operator on $C([0,1])$ defined by $(Tu)(t) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} u(x)^2\,\mathrm dx$. Show that $T$ is a contraction mapping on the closed ball of radius $\dfrac14$ in $C([0,1])$.

From a different thread ([Regarding integral operators being contractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627972/regarding-integral-operators-being-contractions)) it was recommended to use the fact that $u^2 - v^2 = (u+v)(u-v)$ but it's getting me nowhere.
Been away from functional analysis for a while and having some trouble getting back into it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\int (u-v) (u+v)| \leq \sqrt {\int (u-v)^{2}} \sqrt {\int (u+v)^{2}}$. For $u$ and $v$ in the given ball $|u+v| \leq \frac  1 2$ so  $\sqrt {\int (u+v)^{2}} \leq \frac 1  2$.  Of course $\sqrt {\int (u-v)^{2}} \leq \|u-v\|$.

Comment: @mathhelpmepls There was  a typo. I have corrected the answer.